# Prove that G-x-y has a perfect matching iff x and y are on opposite sides where G is Hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

Question: Suppose G is Hamiltonian bipartite graph with $ x , y \in V(G) $. Prove that $G-x-y$ has a perfect matching if and only if $x$ and $y$ are on the opposite sides of the graph.

Proof:  $\Rightarrow$ Assume that G-x-y has a perfect matching. Since we also know that G is Hamiltonian, |A| = |B| where A and B are the partitions of the G. Therefore, if x and y are not in the opposite partitions, (WLOG, say A) |A| = |B| - $2$. Therefore, there can not be a perfect matching between inequal partitions.

$\Leftarrow$: To be honest, I do not have any brillant ideas for this part. It is very clear actually, because we have a Hamiltonian cycle, which is $ ({x_1}, {y_1}, {x_2}, {y_2},...,{y_n},{x_1})$, and pulling two vertices out will create a hole between the path,therefore I can imagine the matching. However, I could not solve it rigorously.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT for the other direction: Let $C$ be a Hamiltonian cycle  of $G$ [which is on an even number of vertices]. Then, as you noted already, $G-x-y$; $x \in A; y \in B$ has a perfect matching if [not necessarily only if but we just need if] $C-x-y$ has a perfect matching.

Observe however, that if $x$ and $y$ are on different sides, then [as $G$ is bipartite] every path from $x$ to $y$ in $G$ has an odd number of edges [as each edge in $G$ goes from one side to the other] and thus an even number of vertices. Thus each of the two paths from $x$ to $y$ in $C$ has an even number of vertices. So, can you use this to see that $C-x-y$ consists of two paths each with an even number of vertices, and thus $C-x-y$ has a perfect matching, and [from the above paragraph] that this suffices.

Comment: To be honest, I got the idea but you said Hint, however, it seems like a whole completed proof. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is infact a completed proof. I started writing and ended up filling the details

Comment: Oh, I got it now! Thank you so much, and assuming that the right arrow direction of mine is correct also, the problem is solved. Thank you Mike.

Comment: @i_hate_pure_math Good! I am happy to help.